# scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation giving apparantly wrong results

Tags: python, rotation

For the below code,

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
for theta in [0,10,80,90,100,135,170,180,185,300]:
    r = Rotation.from_euler('zxy', [theta,theta,theta], degrees=True)
    print(f"for theta = {theta} we get {r.as_euler('zxy', degrees=True)}")
```

the output is:

```
for theta = 0 we get [0. 0. 0.]
for theta = 10 we get [10. 10. 10.]
for theta = 80 we get [80. 80. 80.]
/path/to/file.py:52: UserWarning: Gimbal lock detected. Setting third angle to zero since it is not possible to uniquely determine all angles.
  print(f"for theta = {theta} we get {r.as_euler('zxy', degrees=True)}")
for theta = 90 we get [-0.         89.99999879  0.        ]
for theta = 100 we get [-80.  80. -80.]
for theta = 135 we get [-45.  45. -45.]
for theta = 170 we get [-10.  10. -10.]
for theta = 180 we get [-7.01670930e-15  1.27222187e-14 -7.01670930e-15]
for theta = 185 we get [ 5. -5.  5.]
for theta = 300 we get [-60. -60. -60.]
```

In the above output the result for `theta=0,10,80` is consistent but cannot understand the results for other values of `theta`. `theta=90` can be ignored. Hopefully this is not a bug and there should be a mathematical explanation as to how scipy is calculating this.

Lastly I largely want a python code which can convert rotation matrix to euler angles. This would solve my problem and the scipy inbuilt function was just one way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading a bit on rotation matrices I found that Euler angles to Rotation matrices is not a one-to-one mapping but a many-to-one mapping. For example, for `theta=100` both `[100,100,100]` and `[-80.  80. -80.]` produce the same rotation matrix.

Infact according to equation (12) of *Malcolm D. Shuster, F. Landis Markley, “General formula for extraction the Euler angles”, Journal of guidance, control, and dynamics, vol. 29.1, pp. 215-221. 2006*

[image]

`[-80, 80, -80]` is equivalent to `[-80+180, 180-80, (-80-180)mod2pi] = [100, 100, 100]` ! if lambda in above equation is chosen to be pi/2.

Thus output of Scipy is correct and not a bug.